# How to show instantly all values of constants in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, ide, constants, pydev

When I code and see a lot of constants and I need to debug it, this is very hard. Especially when I am dealing with regexp. How can I change those constants and see their values? This will be great if I can use some shortcut and even better when those constants will be highlighted.

**EDIT:** I don't want to do this while debugging. I want to do this while writing code.

Comment: you say you need it in editor window... but in which form?... Maybe in Ctrl+Space context menu with name_of_the_constanct=value?

Comment: I want this: key+key+key -> all CONSTANT_VARIABLE will change to their values and will be highlighted.

Comment: still not clear.. please edit your question make an example or a drawing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the value of a constant from a reference, just hover over it with the mouse (the tooltip shown should have the value of the constant).

Another option could be pressing F3 to go to the definition and later just do Alt+Back to go back to the place you were before.

Some other things that could be of use:

- If you want to see the constants in the current file, you can just select the word and wait for the mark occurrences to chime in...
- If you wanted to rename all in the current file, Ctrl+2+R (this may also be used to browse the occurrences in the current file by pressing tab).
- If you want to search all references in the workspace: Ctrl+Shift+G (if you want you could rename matches from that search result window).
- If you want to directly rename all references in the workspace: Shift+Alt+R.